# polymer core-list model use in template

Tags: polymer

I am trying to give a child element of a core-list access to the whole model that is being used to create it.  Something like this:

```
<core-list data="{{data}}">
  <template>
    <my-custom-element data="{{model}}">
      <h2>{{model.title}}</h2>
    </my-custom-element>
  </template>
</core-list>
```

The h2 element is expressed fine when inflating the template in the custom element, but I can't find any way of making the model available to my custom element.

Is this the expected behavior, or is this a bug in the way core-list is driving the template?

**EDIT**

The contents of my-custom element would be something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" layout vertical attributes="data">
  <template>
     <div layout horizontal>
       <core-image src={{data.image.url}}></core-image>
       <span flex><content select="h2"></content></span>
     </div>
     <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

So you can see that I am trying to access the full model that was presented to the template in the core-list.

**EDIT 2**

As requested I have created an example on codepen (sorry for the time it took, but I am new to codepen!)

http://codepen.io/m5p3nc3r/pen/mywoXO

The rather embarrassing thing is that this example is working as I would have expected.  If I work out what I was doing wrong in my real code, I will post my findings back here.

Thanks for you help anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You want use the "model" to fill the H2 tag and use the "model" inside your "my-custom-element" Polymer element ? It's interesting, I'll try it. I don't see why this cannot be possible.

Comment: I have updated the original question to add an example of my-custom-element that I hope explains my problem a bit better.

Comment: A concrete example would help. Can you post something on codepen?

Comment: concrete example added - although this is working as I would have expected!